# Is it possible to use a enum like UITableViewCellStyle as parameter of a method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, enums

I want to have a enum as a parameter of my function. Would this work?

```
(UIFont*) myMethodName:(UITableViewCellStyle) cellStyle {
    //...
    if (cellStyle == UITableViewCellStyleValue2)
        // ...
}
```

Then I would call the method like this way

```
UIFont *resultFont = [self myMethodName:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];
```

Only the following parameters should be allowed: 
UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
   UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Would this work?* → Yes
- *Only the following parameters should be allowed:* → No it is not possible to restrict the input to just these values, i.e.

  ```
  UIFont *resultFont = [self myMethodName:12345];
  ```

  will still compile (assuming you are not using Objective-C++).

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
typedef enum _MyType {
    type_a = -1,
    type_b = 0,
    type_c = 1,
} MyType;

...

- (void) someMethod:(MyType)type {
    if (type == type_a) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

(This feels like an unnecessarily short answer but I can't think of anything else to add!)

Comment: That's all I wanted to know ;)